# What's the difference between a iterator = null and hasnext = false?

Tags: java, list, null, iterator, listiterator

I am writing a code to flatten a 2d list, like `[[1,2], [3], [4,5,6]]`. I want them to be in one list like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.
when i want to check if coliter is at the end of a one row, i want them to change to the next row.

```
while ((colIter == null || !colIter.hasNext()) && rowIter.hasNext())
```

When i am doing this, i am thinking about what's the difference between `colIter == null` and `!colIter.hasNext()`?

```
private Iterator<List<Integer>> rowIter;
private Iterator<Integer> colIter;

public Solution_2(List<List<Integer>> vec2d) {
    rowIter = vec2d.iterator();
    colIter = Collections.emptyIterator();
}

@Override
public Integer next() {
    return colIter.next();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    while ((colIter == null || !colIter.hasNext()) && rowIter.hasNext()) {
        colIter = rowIter.next().iterator();
    }
    return colIter != null && colIter.hasNext();
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    while (colIter == null && rowIter.hasNext()) {
        colIter = rowIter.next().iterator();
        if (colIter != null) {
            colIter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One is checking an object exists and the other is obtaining information from an object?  If that's really all you're asking, you've got a lot of extraneous information in your question.  You should probably [edit] it down to make it more clear.

Comment: In the code above, colIter == null cannot be true in any kind of circumstances since you always have it set to a non-null object. !colIter.hasNext() checks if the current colIter Iterator has reached the end of the List and doesn't have any next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take your nested list...

```
[ [1,2], [3], [4,5,6] ]
```

...you could think of it in a different fashion.

```
0: [1, 2]
1: [3]
2: [4, 5, 6]
```

That is to say, you have a two-dimensional representation of your list because of its nested property.  Row 0 contains the values 1 and 2, row 1 contains 3, and row 2 contains 4, 5, and 6.

When you write

```
colIter == null || !colIter.hasNext()) && rowIter.hasNext()
```

What you're checking for is this:

- ***Is* there a column?**
- If there is,

  - Have we **exhausted the column iteration** AND do we have more things to read from our rows?

Consider a nested list in this fashion:

```
0: [1, 2]
1: []
2: [3, 4, 5]
```

For Row 1, there definitely *is* a column, but we don't have any values to process and there's something else to do, so we can move past this record.

If we're at the end of the nested list, then I would expect a call to `colIter.next()` to throw a `NoSuchElementException` instead of returning `null`.  You *may* want to look into that.

Comment: Great Explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **Q:** I am writing a code to flatten a 2d list, like `[[1,2], [3], [4,5,6]`. I want them to be in one list like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

**A:** For sake of brevity, use the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) feature [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) which flattens the structure:

```
List<Integer> list = vec2d.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Prior to [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) version, there is enough the for-each usage for this issue.

> **Q:** ... what's the difference between `colIter == null` and `!colIter.hasNext()`?

**A:** The `colIter == null` checks whether the Iterator itself is null or not. By default, returning an iterator from any existing collection never results in a `null` alike Iterator.

`colIter.hasNext()` is a method called from the Iterator which according to its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) returns `true` if the iteration has more elements that implies that the subsequent call of [`Iterator::next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) will return an element and will not throw `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Suggesting streams is not tangential to the discussion.  Let them figure out how to do it before they rely on syntactic sugar.

Comment: I have *perused* your answer and remain steadfast on my assessment.